# Umbraco upgrade error "current version different from config status"

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I upgraded Umbraco from v7.1.2 to v7.2.1 on development env., upgraded the database without problem. I need to deploy this version to staging without deleting or changing existing db content. My idea was to copy the upgraded files to staging server and then (hopefully) just go to staging url and finish the upgrade process.

When I try this, I always get login page which doesn't let me continue with the installation. When I look in the log, there is error message "current version different from config status". When I change umbraco version in web.config from 7.1.2 to 7.2.1, I can access the home page of staging website, but I can't get to the installation wizard.

What should I do in order to run the installer and upgrade the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did a major update to an Umbraco installation. The way I handled it, was to take a full backup of the production database and use that locally on my dev enviroment, and then run the installation on that db using the updgraded Umbraco version.

I then deployed both the updated database and website file directory (except for App_browsers, App_config and media) to the staging enviroment. You also need to remember to change the connection strings in web.config file when changing enviroment. When we were sure everything worked correctly, we deployed everything on production as well.

I don't know if there is an official way to do it, but I've found this to be the safest and easiest way.
It is, however, recommended that you never copy the install folder to the live enviroment, and make sure to delete it when you are done upgrading.

The drawback is, that you need to be aware of the maintenance window for the website in which no new changes will be persisted. (The time between you taking the backup, and deploying it on production again, overwriting the old one)

Comment: I was thinking of trying that if everything else fails. I was looking for a procedure that could allow db upgrade directly on the staging/production after deploying files.